# sending a form in 2 pieces

Tags: php, html

so i created a form in 2 contact and offerte. but now i want to send the datta appart.
if the selected the contact the must send only the data in contact.
but if the selected the offerte the must send all the data.
how do i do this in php? i tried tis way but i failed

```
   if ($onderwerp = 'Contact'){
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$voornaam = $_POST['voornaam']; 
$naam = $_POST['naam']; 
$telefoon = $_POST['telefoon'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$onderwerp = $_POST['onderwerp'];
$bericht = $_POST['bericht'];
    
$mailto = "test@desloovere.one";
$headers = "From: ".$mail;
$txt = "Nieuwe e-mail van " .$onderwerp.
    ".\n\n voornaam: ".$voornaam.
    ".\n\n naam: ".$naam.
    ".\n\n telefoon: ".$telefoon.
    ".\n\n onderwerp: ".$onderwerp.
    ".\n\n bericht: \n\n".$bericht;

mail($mailto,$onderwerp,$txt,$headers);
;

    if ($onderwerp = 'offerte'){
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$voornaam = $_POST['voornaam']; 
$naam = $_POST['naam']; 
$telefoon = $_POST['telefoon'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$onderwerp = $_POST['onderwerp'];
$bericht = $_POST['bericht'];
$diensten = $_POST['diensten'];
$land = $_POST['land'];
$bedrijf = $_POST['bedrijf'];
$btw = $_POST['BTW'];
$straat = $_POST['straat'];
$huisnummer = $_POST['huisnummer'];
$gemeente = $_POST['gemeente'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    
$mailto = "test@desloovere.one";
$headers = "From: ".$mail;
$txt = "Nieuwe e-mail van " .$onderwerp.
    ".\n\n voornaam: ".$voornaam.
    ".\n\n naam: ".$naam.
    ".\n\n telefoon: ".$telefoon.
    ".\n\n diensten: ".$diensten.
    ".\n\n land: ".$land.
    ".\n\n bedrijf: ".$bedrijf.
    ".\n\n btw: ".$btw.
    ".\n\n straat: ".straat.
    ".\n\n huinummer: ".$huisnummer.
    ".\n\n gemeente: ".$gemeente.
    ".\n\n postcode: ".$postcode.
    ".\n\n onderwerp: ".$onderwerp.
    ".\n\n bericht: \n\n".$bericht;

mail($mailto,$onderwerp,$txt,$headers);
;
$naam = $naam;
$voornaam = $voornaam;
}
```

Comment: your first line should use `===` to compare (instead of `=` which is used to assign values to variables): `if ($onderwerp === 'Contact'){` (and similarly `if ($onderwerp === 'offerte'){` below).

Comment: shouldn't the first line be if($_POST['onderwerp'] == 'Contact'){